# What is this: main:for(...){...} doing?

Tags: javascript

I pulled up the [NWmatcher source code](http://code.google.com/p/nwevents/source/browse/trunk/nwmatcher-1.1.1.js) for some light morning reading and noticed this odd bit of code I'd never seen in javascript before:

```
main:for(/*irrelevant loop stuff*/){/*...*/}
```

This snippet can be found in the `compileGroup` method on line 441 (nwmatcher-1.1.1)

```
return new Function('c,s,d,h',
    'var k,e,r,n,C,N,T,X=0,x=0;main:for(k=0,r=[];e=N=c[k];k++){' + 
         SKIP_COMMENTS + source + 
    '}return r;'
);
```

Now I figured out what `main:` is doing on my own. If you have a loop within a loop and want to skip to the next iteration of the outer loop (without completing the inner OR the outer loop) you can execute `continue main`. Example:

```
// This is obviously not the optimal way to find primes...
function getPrimes(max) {
    var primes = [2], //seed
        sqrt = Math.sqrt,
        i = 3, j, s;

    outer: for (; i <= max; s = sqrt(i += 2)) {
        j = 3;
        while (j <= s) {
            if (i % j === 0) {
                // if we get here j += 2 and primes.push(i) are
                // not executed for the current iteration of i
                continue outer;
            }
            j += 2;
        }
        primes.push(i);
    }
    return primes;
}
```

**What is this called?

Are there any browsers that don't support it?

Are there other uses for it other than `continue`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [labeled continue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/continue#Example.3a_Using_continue_with_a_label).  You can also use [labeled break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/break).  It's standard since ECMAScript 3.  It works essentially the same way [in Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).

Answer (score 1):

That is simply an example of using Labels to control flow. It is part of the standard and, as far as I know, all browsers support it.

As for other uses, check out exactly what you can do with it at (in addition to `continue`, labels can be used with `break`):

[Tutorialspoint - JavaScript Loop Control with break and continue](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_loop_control.htm)